# Jasmine doesn't recognize Pusher.unsubscribe

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to find if pusher subscribes to a channel if the channel name is unknown? Apparently Jasmine doesn't know it this way:

```
 subscribe: function(booking_request_id) {
      if(channel && pusher) pusher.unsubscribe(); // error :  not implemented thrown
      channel = pusher.subscribe('booking_requests_' + booking_request_id);
      channel.bind('async_notification', function (data) {
         $rootScope.$apply(function () {
         callback(data);
        });
      });
    }
```